# feel the floor shaken

Tags: past-participles, participles

Is "shaken" used properly in the following? Normally, I'd expect "shaking." But I'm wondering if the verb "shake" can take an object followed by a past participle.

Joe can feel the floor **shaken** when he walks in the house.

Comment: *Joe can feel the floor **shaking** when he walks in the house.*

Comment: How about "Joe felt the floor shaken when he entered the house"?

Comment: With your specific example it's almost impossible to think of any small modifications that might allow you to replace Continuous Participle ***shaking*** with Past Participle ***shaken***. But you *could* make such a change in, for example, *Joe looked at his ice-cream **melting / melted** on the floor*. And hopefully you can easily see what difference *that* would make to the meaning.

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? Was it online or did you make it up?

Comment: You could google "felt the floor shaken" yourself.

Comment: It occurs in one of Wilkie Collins' works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The participle "shaken" is passive.

With verbs like shake there are two forms:

> The floor shakes.

> The train shakes the floor as it goes past.

Note that in the first sense, "the floor" is the subject, and the verb is intransitive.  In the second, the verb is transitive and "the floor" is the object.

The second form could be expressed in the passive

> The floor is shaken (by the train as it goes past).

Note that the use of the passive implies the existence of an actor (the train)

So a passive participle "Joe can feel the floor shaken when he walks in the house" implies that there is *something* shaking the floor.

Perhaps if Joe keeps a dragon in the basement, he could feel the floor shaken *by the dragon*.  But if not it would be more natural to say "Joe can feel the floor shaking."